# Show scrollbar after given delay

Tags: android, view, scrollbar

is it possible to set a delay at which the scroll bar at the right side appears? The idea is that when the user begins to scroll, the scroll bar does not show up immediately, but if the user scrolls long enough.

I was looking for some time now and found just a getter method getScrollDefaultDelay (), which gets the time in ms when the scroll bar dissapears. How could I control the delay in my case?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the scroll bar using `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled` and listen for "scroll changes", either by overriding `onScrollChanged` or by defining some sort of scroll listener. If the users scrolls, send a delayed message to a `Handler`. When the user scrolls again, remove the message and send a new one with the same delay. If the message runs through, display the scrollbar again. When he scrolls again, hide it again. Rinse and repeat.

You'll probably want to disable default scrollbar fading, alas that's apparently only possible starting with API Version 5, using `setScrollbarFadingEnabled`.

Comment: Interesting aproach. I also found the setVerticalScrollBarEnabled and disabled the scroll bar, though I didn't think of listening to onScrollChanged events and manually enabling/disabling it. Thank you Timo for sharing, keep it up!